# What is a robust estimator?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

From this discussion of 1muflon1, I see the meaning of [efficient and consistent estimator](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47659/what-are-the-asymptotic-properties-of-an-estimator) regarding to the asymptotic properties. I am wondering what is a robust estimator?

Comment: Hi! Did you try to look this up yourself? It seems like there are several results available on [Google](http://www3.grips.ac.jp/~yamanota/Lecture_Note_9_Heteroskedasticity) and even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) that explain this.

Comment: Without getting into the weeds on the matter, robustness in general should be taken to mean: 'robustness against uncertainty in estimation.' Now, in accordance with @Giskard, I would agree that it's such a broad topic (i.e. such large causes of uncertainty), that it requires preliminary reading in order to refine your question, and hope for a suitably precise answer.

Comment: Hi: An estimator's robustness is generally defined by it's breakdown point. Heuristically, speaking, the breakdown point is the number of "bad" ( contaminated if you will ), observations there would have to be in a sample before the estimator became totally useless. For example, the median could deal with (n/2 - 1) while the mean can get useless when there is only one contaminated observation. Google for "breakdown point" if you want all of the gory details.

Comment: There are at least two meanings: robustness to outliers or contaminated data (the one mentioned by mark leeds) is the statistical one, while econometricians relate robustness to model misspecification.

Comment: EB3112's answer is probably what is being referred to. There is a non-zero chance a "robust estimator" refers to the use of robust standard errors, but it would be more standard to say "robust standard errors" to refer to that usage of "robust".